# NIntegrate of surface area of intersecting spheres yields zero

Tags: numerical-integration, lattices

I have a bunch of spheres (it's actually [diamond cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) structure. The 0.6 radius doesn't matter),

```
img = {Ball[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, 0.6], Ball[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{-1/2, 1/2, -1/2}, 0.6], Ball[{1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{-1, -1, -1}, 0.6], Ball[{-1, -1, 1}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{-1, 1, -1}, 0.6], Ball[{-1, 1, 1}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{1, -1, -1}, 0.6], Ball[{1, -1, 1}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{1, 1, -1}, 0.6], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.6], Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 0.6], Ball[{0, 1, 0}, 0.6], Ball[{-1, 0, 0}, 0.6], 
  Ball[{0, 0, -1}, 0.6], Ball[{0, -1, 0}, 0.6]};
```

I am interested in its volume and surface area for any radius inside a unit box. It looks like this (`Show[Graphics3D[img], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`)
[image: 3D graphics intersecting spheres]

By doing

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[
    Or@@((Norm[{x,y,z}-#]<=0.5) &/@ Cases[img,Ball[pos_,_]->pos])
], {x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]
```

I can get the volume when $r=.5$.

Then I tried (`<=` changed to `==`)

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[
    Or@@((Norm[{x,y,z}-#]==0.5) &/@ Cases[img,Ball[pos_,_]->pos])
], {x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]
```

in an attempt to get surface area. But it gives zero. Where was I wrong?

### Edit (2015-06-14)

I ran the methods of two of the answers below over $radius=\sqrt{2}/2$. I kept getting:

```
Unable to compute the area of region \
RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}],RegionDifference[\
RegionDifference[RegionDifference[RegionDifference[RegionDifference[\
RegionDifference[RegionDifference[RegionDifference[<<2>>],Ball[<<2>>]]\
,Ball[{<<3>>},Power[<<2>>]]],Ball[{1,0,0},1/Sqrt[2]]],Ball[{0,1,0},1/\
Sqrt[2]]],Ball[{-1,0,0},1/Sqrt[2]]],Ball[{0,0,-1},1/Sqrt[2]]],Ball[{0,\
-1,0},1/Sqrt[2]]]]. >>
```

They both work fine for 0.5. The code is simply as follows.

```
imgballs = {Ball[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{-1/2, 1/2, -1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{-1, -1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, -1, 1}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{-1, 1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, 1, 1}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{1, -1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{1, -1, 1}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{1, 1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.5], Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 0.5], Ball[{0, 1, 0}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, 0, 0}, 0.5], 
 Ball[{0, 0, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{0, -1, 0}, 0.5]};

(* Michael Seifert's method *)
imgspheres = imgballs /. Ball[x___, 0.5] -> Sphere[x, Sqrt[2]/2];
imgballs2 = imgballs /. Ball[x___, y_] -> Ball[x, Sqrt[2]/2];
reglist = Table[RegionDifference[
   RegionIntersection[imgspheres[[i]], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]], 
   RegionUnion[Drop[imgballs2, {i}]]], {i, 1, Length[imgspheres]}];
Area /@ reglist
Total[%]

(* george2079's method *)
MapIndexed[(Area@
  RegionIntersection[
   Fold[RegionDifference, #, Delete[imgballs2, #2]], 
   Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]]) &, imgspheres]
Total@%
```

Any idea to fix this? I'm actually interested in this radius.

Comment: The area calculation fails because you are depending on the practically zero probability of `NIntegrate`'s initial sampling happening to *exactly* hit a surface.   Try to formulate it as an integral over the surface of each sphere, with a `Boole` test if the surface element is in the box.

Comment: @george2079 Do integration for each sphere and add them up? How can I deal with the intersections then?

Comment: The intersections are just lines (or points), and so they have zero area.  Imagine, for example, a finite surface in the _xy_-plane and one in the _xz_-plane, intersecting at a line segment along the _x_-axis.  The combined surface area of the complex is just the sum of the individual planar surfaces.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, the intersections are lines. What I meant is the parts that overlap. For instance, look at the $1/8$ sphere on the upper left corner. A large part of its area is inside another sphere. I don't wanna count that.

Comment: For the areas that go outside the box, you could use @george2079's suggestion to use a `Boole` test.  There's also a dead-simple method using the `Area` function (available in Mathematica 10), which I've put in my answer below.

Comment: Your last integral is set up as the triple integral over a volume (cube) of a function that is zero almost everywhere.  It is not the integral you seek and its value is actually zero.  (To answer "Where was [I] wrong?")

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73282/how-i-calculate-the-volume-of-multiple-intersecting-spheres  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46412/surface-area-of-intersecting-spheres

Comment: re:latest edit. I'd assume you've hit on a special case where some spheres are just touching, or have a very small overlap.

Comment: @george2079 Exactly. That's a critical point I am interested for the specific structure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're running Mathematica 10 or above, there's a dead simple method using the new `Area` function:

```
newimg = img /. Ball[x___, 0.6] -> Sphere[x, 0.5]
Total[Map[Area[RegionIntersection[#, Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]]] &, newimg]]

(* 25.1327 *)
```

Note a few things here:

1. Mathematica considers `Ball` to be a 3D object;  if we want its surface area we have to use `Sphere` instead.
2. Mathematica is much better at dealing with the individual spheres and their intersections with the cube than it is at dealing with the whole complex at once.  In principle you could also use `RegionUnion` to define the entire surface as the union of these `Sphere`s, but when I tried that approach Mathematica just gave up.
3. Similarly, you could try using `ImplicitRegion`, almost as you did above, to define the complex, and then feed that into `Area`.  However, I tried this just now and Mathematica is still thinking about it.  (**EDIT:**  I aborted the evaluation after about an hour with no results.)  The above code runs in just a few seconds on my machine.

***EDIT:***  It was pointed out in the comments that the OP may have wanted to exclude any of the spheres that lie within another sphere.  This can be done as well, though it's a little trickier.  Basically, we need to take the `RegionDifference` between each `Sphere` and all of the other `Ball`s:

```
imgballs = {Ball[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{-1/2, 1/2, -1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{-1, -1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, -1, 1}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{-1, 1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, 1, 1}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{1, -1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{1, -1, 1}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{1, 1, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.5], Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 0.5], Ball[{0, 1, 0}, 0.5], Ball[{-1, 0, 0}, 0.5], 
   Ball[{0, 0, -1}, 0.5], Ball[{0, -1, 0}, 0.5]};
imgspheres = imgballs /. Ball[x___, 0.5] -> Sphere[x, 0.5];
reglist = Table[RegionDifference[
  RegionIntersection[imgspheres[[i]], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]], 
  RegionUnion[Drop[imgballs, {i}]]], {i, 1, Length[imgspheres]}];
Area /@ reglist
Total[%]

(* {2.29981, 2.29981, 2.29981, 2.29981, 0.392699, 0.182252, 0.182252,
    0.392699, 0.182252, 0.392699, 0.392699, 0.182252, 1.1499, 1.1499, \
    1.1499, 1.1499, 1.1499, 1.1499} *) 

(* 18.3984 *)
```

Just for fun, let's try to visualize this region.  I had to do some tricky shenanigans here to keep `DiscretizeRegion` happy;  specifically, I found that if I took the differences with *all* of the other spheres, Mathematica couldn't keep track of which differences made a difference (i.e., which other spheres actually intersected a given sphere.)  So I defined the *adjmatrix* below to pick out the balls that intersected a given sphere.  I then had to make sure that I was subtracting *something* from each sphere, hence the ugly `If` statement that subtracts a "dummy" ball if there is no "real" ball intersecting a given sphere.

```
adjmatrix = Outer[((4 \[Pi] 0.5^3/3) > Volume[RegionIntersection[#1, #2]] > 
  0) &, imgballs, imgballs];
reglist = 
  Table[RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[imgspheres[[i]], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]], 
   If[Pick[imgballs, adjmatrix[[i]]] != {}, RegionUnion[Pick[imgballs, adjmatrix[[i]]]], Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 0.1]]], 
   {i, 1, Length[imgspheres]}]
Show[DiscretizeRegion /@ reglist, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The area of this new `reglist` is the same as before, as one can easily check.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution! I actually tried `ImplicitRegion` before posting the question, and you are right it can't work out.

Comment: Doesn't this method also count the area of a sphere lies within another sphere, which @Fred said he doesn't want to count?

Comment: Hmm, good point.  The original code he tried to use would have had that same problem as well, though, (it would have counted all points that were the proper distance from one of the centers, regardless of whether they were inside a different sphere), so I'm a little confused.

Comment: I've now modified my code to address @Fred's desire to only count surfaces that lie outside any of the other spheres.

Comment: This is awesome. I really appreciate your and @george2079 's help!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I was trying to run it over radius == sqrt(2)/2, and it doesn't seem to work out. May I invite you to take a look? See my update above.

Comment: I don't have MM 10 here at home, so I can't muck about with the code myself right now.  However, one suggestion:  see if using `0.707107` instead `Sqrt[2]/2` helps matters.  I suspect that Mathematica is trying to calculate everything exactly now that you're providing it with exact input, and choking on the calculation as a result.

Comment: Using the numerical value doesn't seem to help either;  Mathematica can't calculate the areas of some of the spheres.  It can calculate the areas of some of them, though, particularly the ones entirely contained in the unit cell.  I would focus on calculating the areas of one of those;  if you can do that, then you can multiply the result by 8 (the number of atoms per unit cell) to get the result you need.  You'll need to let the spheres go outside the cuboid for this radius value, though.

Comment: Also, note that for any radius values greater than $\sqrt{2}/2$, you'll start to intersect other spheres outside the unit cell.  For example, the sphere centered at {1/2, 1/2, 1/2} will intersect the sphere at {3/2,3/2,1/2}.

Comment: Simply using numerical value has no effect. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

The old fashion way:

```
 r = .5;
 NIntegrate[ r^2 Sin[phi] Boole[And @@ ((-1 < # < 1 ) & /@ 
     (#[[1]] + 
       CoordinateTransform[
        "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, theta, phi}]))],
           {theta, 0, 2 Pi} , {phi, 0, Pi} ] & /@ img // Total
```

> 25.1327

Edit: this is excluding areas that are inside any other sphere:

```
 centers = img[[All, 1]];
 NIntegrate[
    p = #[[1]] +
       CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, theta, phi}];
    r^2 Sin[phi] Boole[ Min[(Norm[p - #]) & /@
          Complement[centers, {#[[1]]}] ] > r &&
      (And @@ ((-1 < # < 1) & /@ p))],
         {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {phi, 0, Pi}] & /@ img // Total
```

It is running very slowly and throwing convergence warnings however..

...finally finished with result:

> 19.181

This figure is generated using `EvaluationMonitor` to capture all the sample points that are used to compute the area. (gives an idea of why it is so slow )

[image]

### edit

a variant on Michael's approach..

```
 MapIndexed[(Area@RegionIntersection[
      Fold[ RegionDifference, #  , Delete[ imgballs, #2] ],
        Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]]) &, imgspheres] 
 Total@%
```

> 18.3984

Comment: You get the same result. But like @Rahul said above, doesn't this count the overlapping part? Sorry I am new to Mathematica and the code is kinda hard for me to grasp.

Comment: After doing some research, I start to appreciate your code. Thanks!

Comment: I was running into a new problem when computing radius equal to sqrt(2)/2. Could you please take a look at my update above? Thanks!!

Comment: Cant test it , but I think you need to replace `Delete[ imgballs, #2]` with something like `Select[ imgballs , Function[{ball}, Norm[ball[[1]]-#[[1]]]<2 r]]`.  If that works change `MapIndexed` to `Map` as well.

Comment: make that ` 0 < Norm[ball[[1]]-#[[1]]]<2 r ` (still untested, no v10  here..)

Comment: It doesn't work out. I believe your method is correct. But Mathematica keeps giving `"Unable to compute the area of region \
RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}],RegionDifference[\
RegionDifference[RegionDifference[RegionDifference[Sphere[{1/2,1/2,1/\
2},0.707],Ball[{1,1,1},0.707]],Ball[{0,0,1},0.707]],Ball[{1,0,0},0.\
707]],Ball[{0,1,0},0.707]]]."` I tried `RegionDifference[Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.7], 
  Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.7]] // Area` and got the same error

Comment: I tend to think it's a bug. `RegionDifference[Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.5]] // Area` works, so does `RegionDifference[Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.5], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.7]] // Area` and `RegionDifference[Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 0.7], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 0.5]] // Area`.

Answer (score 2):

Another version 10 approach (barring errors on my part) to address volume as well as surface area. The (limitations of region) discretizations render only approximations, cf george2079 better numeric integration and the neat approach of Michael Seifert...both of which I have upvoted.

```
cb = Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}];
i = RegionUnion @@ (RegionIntersection[cb, #] & /@ img);
t = RegionUnion @@ img;
o = RegionUnion @@ (RegionDifference[#, cb] & /@ img);
in = DiscretizeRegion[i];
tr = DiscretizeRegion[t];
out = DiscretizeRegion[o];
a0 = Total[Area /@ MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[tr], 2]];
a1 = Total[Area /@ MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[in], 2]];
a2 = Total[Area /@ MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[out], 2]];
sa=a1 - (a1 + a2 - a0)/2
vol=Volume[in]
```

The surface area (needed to subtract the area of the cut sides): 17.1081, and volume: 5.42381.

The following renderings take some time (but I present for fun...and perhaps to correct my misconceptions):

```
rp0 = RegionPlot3D[t, PlotPoints -> 60, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
    Background -> Black];
rp1 = RegionPlot3D[i, PlotPoints -> 100, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, Background -> Black];
rp2 = RegionPlot3D[o, PlotPoints -> 40, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
    Background -> Black];
```

then

```
TabView[{"Full object" -> rp0, "Restricted object" -> rp1, 
  "Complement" -> rp2}]
```

[image]

Comment: So does the `18.3984` contains cut sides? I don't want these cut sides actually. I'm confused again.

Comment: You can easily and efficiently compute the area using `Area@RegionBoundary@tr` etc.

Comment: @RunnyKine thank you for educating me in this regard. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Fred the count is the polygons that make up the mesh discretization.